# How to be sure that application does autostart on Windows boot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, application-launch, autostart

I used some application (CrystalDiskInfo) - portable version (directory, without installing into system), I placed it into C partition. I marked autostart option in there. But I wanna be sure that it starts when system loads, but I can't find it in processes list and dond't know exactly name of it's process. What would you recommend for such situations ? When I start itTask Manager > Startup doesn't show this app in the list.

Comment: What specific autostart did you enable? is it one built into CrystalDiskInfo, or an OS feature? I'd disable autostart, login, and examime your processes in a tool like Process Explorer. Then launch it, and see what process pops up, to get the process name.

Comment: @Frank Thomas inside application: Function > Startup.

Comment: There are quite a few ways an app can make itself startup. For example, navigate to shell:startup is one, there are 4 different registry locations where apps can create a startup entry, and there are others. The best way to see if the app starts, is by simply rebooting and see if the app launches. Note that portable versions of programs usually don't write to the OS so usually startup functions don't work. If the portable version is native to the app itself, it could still work though.

Comment: @LPChip thanks, I checked those registry keys, there nothing about this app. And right after start there is no such process. It seems it doesn't autostart.

Comment: Now, you can of course simply create a shortcut to the app in shell:startup to ensure that it starts automatically when windows starts.

Comment: Have you tried to run msconfig? `WIN+R` type msconfig, check boot. Also check the folder you installed program and check name of executable files if you can spot them.

Comment: I'm suprised that no one has mentioned AutoRuns. it lets you search across a wide variety of autostart methods for an object.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest that you install [Winpatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/download.html).

It will give you the ability to control your autostarts and show you what is running.

Best of all, whenever any program tries to insert itself into your autostarts it will throw up an alert so you can decide if that is what you intend.

I consider it indispensable and use it on all my Windows computers.

Answer (score 1):

How to AutoStart an application:

### Windows Task Scheduler

1. Run: taskschd.msc
2. Create Task
3. Triggers Tab: At Startup
4. Actions Tab:
   New → Start a Program → Browse to executable file.

EDIT: Prompted by a fellow member's comment, I found a nice link that has images to follow.
https://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/